# Avoid making repeated Random Integer in different iterations

Tags: functions, programming, random

Assume following code :

```
Do[
   i1 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}];
   i2 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}];
   While[i1 == i2,  i2 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}]] 
   , {k, 1, 4}];`
```

This code makes two `RandomIntegers` which are `i1` and `i2`. I have used `While` loop to avoid making repeated Random numbers in each iteration. But I don't know how it is possible to avoid making repeated Random numbers in whole iterations. For example, following result is the answer after 4 iteration and it is not acceptable :

> ```
>  i1=1, i2=2
>  i1=3, i2=2
>  i1=1, i2=2
>  i1,4, i2=1
> ```

`i1=1` and `i2=2` are repeated twice after 4 iterations.

I would be appreciated if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: You want to store `k` pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Memory inefficient approach:

```
RandomSample[
             DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[5], {2}], {n_, n_}],
             5]
```

or alternatively with `Subsets`.

```
RandomSample[Join[{##}, Reverse /@ {##}] & @@ Subsets[Range[5], {2}], 5]
```

---

Time inefficient approach:

```
list = {};
Do[
 While[
    While[Equal @@ ({i, j} = RandomInteger[5, 2])];
    MemberQ[list, {i, j}]
    ]
   list = Join[list, {{i, j}}];
 , {5}]

list
```

Comment: In fact, I don't want to store the i1 and i2 ! i1 and i2 are inputs for another loop and calculation. I just want to make different random Integers(i1 not equal to i2) in each iteration and for next iterations, I want different i1 and i2 from those which are made in previous itarations.

Comment: @Shellp so you need to store them if you want to check if such pair was generated earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Your method is truly efficient and useful.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (after Kuba comment)

You can use `RandomSample` ,e.g

If the aim is sampling from {1,2,3,4,5}^2:

```
RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], 2]]
```

yielding

```
{{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {5, 3}, {1, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 
  5}, {5, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}, {3, 4}, {2, 
  2}, {5, 4}, {3, 5}, {1, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}}
```

Clearly any sample of length >25 must have a repeated pair

If the diagonal elements are 'bad pairs' then:

```
RandomSample[
 With[{tup = Tuples[Range[5], 2]}, 
  Pick[tup, Not[First@# == Last@#] & /@ tup]]]
```

This was an uglier way than Kuba's `DeleteCases`

Comment: @Kuba my mistake...misunderstood